# creating a win32 dll from the following code using Visual Studio Express 2012

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, dll

I'm trying to build a standard win32 DLL from the following code. I know C# well, but I'm new to C. I'm getting all kinds of compiler errors and have been going at this for the last 4 hours. Could someone please help me put together this simple project? I would be very grateful.

**dll.h**

```
    #ifndef _DLL_H_
    #define _DLL_H_

    #include <windows.h>

    #if BUILDING_DLL
    # define DLLIMPORT __declspec (dllexport)
    #else /* Not BUILDING_DLL */
    # define DLLIMPORT __declspec (dllimport)
    #endif /* Not BUILDING_DLL */

    #define SHARED __attribute__((section(".shr"), shared))

    DLLIMPORT BOOL InstallHook(int i);
    DLLIMPORT BOOL UninstallHook();
    static LRESULT CALLBACK MyWndProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

    #endif /* _DLL_H_ */
```

**dll.cpp**

```
/* Replace "dll.h" with the name of your header */
#include "dll.h"
#include <stdio.h>

HHOOK hHook SHARED = NULL; // Handle des Hooks
HINSTANCE hInstance SHARED = NULL; // Handle der DLL
FILE *fp SHARED;

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain (HINSTANCE hInst     /* Library instance handle. */ ,
                       DWORD reason        /* Reason this function is being called. */ ,
                       LPVOID reserved     /* Not used. */ )
{
    hInstance = hInst;

    /* Returns TRUE on success, FALSE on failure */
    return TRUE;
}

static LRESULT CALLBACK MyWndProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
        if (nCode < 0)
           CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);

        CWPSTRUCT* cw = (CWPSTRUCT*)(lParam);  
           if ( (cw->message == WM_GETMINMAXINFO))
           {
              fprintf(fp, "GETMINMAX! \n"); // Never called!
           }
        return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

DLLIMPORT BOOL UninstallHook()
{
 UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
 hHook = NULL;
 return TRUE;         
}

DLLIMPORT BOOL InstallHook(int i)
{
          fp = fopen("log.txt", "w");

          hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, MyWndProc, hInstance, i);
          if (hHook == NULL)
             return FALSE;   

          return TRUE;          
}
```

Errors being received are: [image: these]

```
Error   14  error C2086: 'int DLLIMPORT' : redefinition 

r:\dev\cpp\win32project4\win32project4\dll.cpp  42  1   Win32Project4
Error   9   error C2086: 'int SHARED' : redefinition    r:\dev\cpp\win32project4\win32project4\dll.cpp  10  1   Win32Project4
Error   10  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'BOOL'    r:\dev\cpp\win32project4\win32project4\dll.cpp  35  1   Win32Project4
Error   12  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'BOOL'    r:\dev\cpp\win32project4\win32project4\dll.cpp  42  1   Win32Project4
Error   2   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'SHARED'  r:\dev\cpp\win32project4\win32project4\dll.cpp  8   1   Win32Project4
Error   4   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'SHARED'  r:\dev\cpp\win32project4\win32project4\dll.cpp  9   1   Win32Project4
Error   7   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'SHARED'  r:\dev\cpp\win32project4\win32project4\dll.cpp  10  1   Win32Project4
Error   6   error C2374: 'SHARED' : redefinition; multiple initialization   r:\dev\cpp\win32project4\win32project4\dll.cpp  9   1   Win32Project4
Error   3   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   r:\dev\cpp\win32project4\win32project4\dll.cpp  8   1   Win32Project4
Error   5   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   r:\dev\cpp\win32project4\win32project4\dll.cpp  9   1   Win32Project4
Error   8   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   r:\dev\cpp\win32project4\win32project4\dll.cpp  10  1   Win32Project4
Error   11  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   r:\dev\cpp\win32project4\win32project4\dll.cpp  35  1   Win32Project4
Error   13  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   r:\dev\cpp\win32project4\win32project4\dll.cpp  42  1   Win32Project4
    18  IntelliSense: a function declared 'dllimport' may not be defined    r:\dev\cpp\Win32Project4\Win32Project4\dll.cpp  35  16  Win32Project4
    19  IntelliSense: a function declared 'dllimport' may not be defined    r:\dev\cpp\Win32Project4\Win32Project4\dll.cpp  42  16  Win32Project4
    15  IntelliSense: expected a ';'    r:\dev\cpp\Win32Project4\Win32Project4\dll.cpp  8   13  Win32Project4
    16  IntelliSense: expected a ';'    r:\dev\cpp\Win32Project4\Win32Project4\dll.cpp  9   21  Win32Project4
    17  IntelliSense: expected a ';'    r:\dev\cpp\Win32Project4\Win32Project4\dll.cpp  10  10  Win32Project4
```

Comment: "I'm getting all kinds of compiler errors". Do tell what specific errors you are getting, including file names and line numbers.

Comment: For one, `__attribute__` is a GCC thing, so if you're building this in Visual Studio using Microsoft's CL (the default) you're not going to get anything good from that at all. Unrelated, there is no reason the header-decl the static MyWndProc. It's static to the .cpp translation unit. The header should only be be declaring the two exported functions. Now, *post the errors you're getting **verbatim** as an edit to your question*.

Comment: Thanks guys. I've added the error messages now. Your info about it being GCC in origin is useful WhozCraig. Thank you